# Import data from excel to vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I import 3 columns from excel to vb .net. Then I want to create a fourth row or new DataGridView and append on each row data from some column. For example I have excel file:

```
12/26/2016  9A  Christmas Day
3/25/2016   9A  Good Friday
3/28/2016   AS  Easter Monday
12/26/2016  AS  St. Stephen's Day
3/25/2016   AS  Easter Monday
1/1/2016    AS  New Year's Day
12/26/2016  BE  Christmas
1/1/2016    BZ  New Year's Day
2/9/2016    BZ  Carnival
5/26/2016   BZ  Corpus Christ
4/21/2016   BZ  Tiradentes Day
12/27/2016  CA  Boxing Day (obs)
10/10/2016  CA  Thanksgiving
```

What I want is, to append new column with content of the 2nd column, where the dates are the same. For example:

```
12/26/2016  9A  Christmas Day 9A AS BE
3/25/2016   9A  Good Friday 9A
3/28/2016   AS  Easter Monday AS
12/26/2016  AS  St. Stephen's Day 9A AS BE
3/25/2016   AS  Easter Monday AS
1/1/2016    AS  New Year's Day AS BZ
12/26/2016  BE  Christmas 9A AS BE
1/1/2016    BZ  New Year's Day AS BZ
2/9/2016    BZ  Carnival BZ
5/26/2016   BZ  Corpus Christ BZ
4/21/2016   BZ  Tiradentes Day BZ
12/27/2016  CA  Boxing Day (obs) CA
10/10/2016  CA  Thanksgiving CA
```

The rows that have same date, will have same values in the fourth column.Column names are (Date, CDR Code, Holiday). Data is the name of the sheet. The code I wrote:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='d:\test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'")
        Dim MyCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Data$]", MyConnection)
        Dim DtSet As New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim MyConnection2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='d:\test.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'")
        Dim MyCommand2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select [CDR Code] from [Data$] WHERE [Date]=[Date] ", MyConnection2)
        Dim DtSet2 As New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand2.Fill(DtSet2)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = DtSet2.Tables(0)
        MyConnection2.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You need to fix your question: "I import 3 columns from excel to vb .net. Then I want to create a fourth row or new DataGridView" - this does not make any sense. You need to be clear

Comment: I insert 3 columns in 1 datagridview. I want to add forth row for reasons described above. If it is not possible to attach 4th row in the datagrid where I imported 3 excel columns, then I create new Datagrid, where will be displayed results that I want.

Comment: "I insert 3 columns .... I want to add forth row " - this is confusing. You need to start thinking more dynamically!! you can use a list of POCO object with 4 properties (`List(Of MyPoco)`) as your `DataSource`, and load 3 properties from DB/Excel (I hope you use Microsoft.ACE.OleDB for that). Once you load your list of data, you just assign `.Datasource = ` property - WOW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    fd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True

    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = fd.FileName
    End If

    Dim dbconnect As New DBConnection(strFileName)
    Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet
    Dim tempTable As DataTable
    Dim tempnames As String
    Dim tempdate As String
    Dim tempds As New System.Data.DataSet



    ds = dbconnect.ExecuteSql("select * from [Data$]")
    tempTable = ds.Tables(0)

    tempTable.Columns.Add("OtherNames", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    For Each Row As DataRow In tempTable.Rows
        tempdate = Row.Item(0)
        tempds = dbconnect.ExecuteSql("select [CDR Code] from [Data$] where [Date]=#" + tempdate + "#")
        tempnames = ""
        For Each Row1 As DataRow In tempds.Tables(0).Rows
            tempnames += Row1.Item(0) + " "
        Next
        Row.Item("OtherNames") = tempnames
    Next

    DataGridView1.DataSource = tempTable

End Sub


End Class
```

And DBConnection Class:

```
Public Class DBConnection
Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

Public Sub New(ByVal FilePath As String)
    con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';")
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    MsgBox("Connection Closed")
    con.Close()
End Sub

Public Function ExecuteSql(ByVal sql As String) As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    Return ds
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For intI As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For intJ As Integer = intI + 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(intI).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(intJ).Cells(0).Value Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(intI).Cells(3).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(intI).Cells(1).Value + DataGridView1.Rows(intJ).Cells(1).Value
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Now u just have to adapt the code. I added a 4th row in dgv1 by the way.

Comment: It works, but it adds only next 1 record that matches. The others that match it does not append.

Comment: any news? did u change anything?

Comment: a friend helped me to solve the problem. Thanks anyways

Comment: something similar to this? or u did something using datatables?

Comment: yes used OleDbConnection and loop with for each row.